# Getting basic facebook profile information ios

Tags: ios, facebook, profile

I have logged in on my iOS app that I am building using the easier method of `FBSDKLoginButton`.

Since all I want is the users name and a link to their facebook I know I can find this under `[FBSDKProfile currentprofile]`.

**My question really is how do I use this?**

I am trying all sorts of combinations but something akin to the below is an example of what I'm doing.

```
[FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];

NSString *name = [[NSString alloc]init];
name = [[FBSDKProfile currentProfile]firstName];
```

I figure since my app now has access which I quickly tested through an if on the `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` so I believe I am primed. My app delegate is all setup also. So shouldn't my above code just work? I mean, I assume `currentProfile` is set if a user is logged in? Maybe? Arghhh!!!

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it guys. Essentially the FBSDKLoginButton logs you in but offers no permissions. Simply ask for them as so;

```
loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"email", @"public_profile"];
```

Then the normal code I tried in my above comment will work. My mistake here is I assumed a simple login would at least give me the public profile. It doesn't, you have to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
FBRequestHandler completionBlock = ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"USER DICTIONARY : %@", user);
};

[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:completionBlock];
```

you can then get the user details from the user dictionary.

Comment: And this will fill in the information for [FBSDKProfile currentProfile]?

Comment: Yes it will, you can see on the console the user dictionary, for example, you can get the last name by using [user objectForKey:@"lastname"];

Comment: So that call;
^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error)

Then you use "user" as if it was a variable you've defined. Is the above call also declaring these variables then? 

It's all a little confusing this Objective-C.

Why doesn't my call [[FBSDKProfile currentProfile]firstName] return anything. Why is "currentProfile" all empty if I have a token?

Comment: Well personally, i dont use the one that you are using, im always using the one i've mentioned above. "user" is now a dictionary where all the information about the current user is stored. You just have to access it by using the objectForKey method. NSString *lastName = [user objectForKey:@"lastname"]; FBRequestConnection is a completion block. It is called when the [FBRequest requestForMe]. I guess you should also read something about dictionaries in objective-c if you are new in this language.

Comment: Will do matey. And thank you.
In C++ I code all day in work like its nothing. Then my evenings are spent cursing our my shiny new Macbook Pro. I'm sure an "AH-HA" moment is just around the corner though.

Comment: Goodluck dude. I guess after a few days if reading and practicing and you'll gonna love this language :)

Comment: That's what people say John, I know it's this crazy managed language. Every time I work something out I have to learn something else. I just assumed that logging into to my app ment my app on that account was cleared. If I check my token, it's valid with a value in it. So I believe the FBSDKProfile object should just....work. 

The saving grace is all I need is their name, link and picture for my app. Then its onto working out the damn formatting sizes for screens. 

My app is almost complete. Thank God I can use C whenever I fancy it.

Comment: No access to FBRequestHandler?